# Python and T-API on OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, opencl, opencv3.0

OpenCV 3.0 now uses T-API (Transparent API), see:

https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/wiki/Opencv3

> it does not need to specify `cv::ocl::Canny`, `cv::gpu::Canny` etc; `cv::Canny` just works on both CPU and GPU.

And this is an example:

http://www.learnopencv.com/opencv-transparent-api/

My question is:

This works with OpenCV with Python? Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: I've already posted the same question a while ago. You can see it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31990646/using-opencl-accelerated-functions-with-opencv3-in-python/32052464#32052464

Answer (score 4):

In C++ to use OpenCL implementations of methods - you should pass `UMat` instead of `Mat`, when you call method from Python with numpy array or so - you effectively call it with `Mat` as argument.

`UMat` was adopted for Python bindings since [OpenCV 3.2](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/ChangeLog#version32). Now you can pass `cv2.UMat(someNumpyMat)` to function just like in C++.

Example:

```
ps, descs_umat = orb.detectAndCompute(cv2.UMat(img), None)
descs = descs_umat.get()
matcher = cv2.BFMatcher(cv2.NORM_HAMMING, crossCheck=True)
res = matcher.match(descs_umat, descs_umat)
```

Comment: I have also updated the content at LearnOpenCV to reflect this change.